# confusion_matrix() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/897DL.png)

As can be seen from above picture,this problem makes me very confused.

Comment: Hello, welcome!  Please don't post images of your code.  See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more helpful guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`labels` is not a positional argument but a keyword argument.

Therefore, you should call the function as follow:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=classes)
```